# Android OS - AMOLED Display Code Development Environment

Tags: android, lcd

I am trying to understand the OS code for AMOLED Displays in Andriod. I wanted to know if I can make changes to Android OS code for the display from a given code base, build the OS and test it on any device ? Just want to play around with the code and test it... 
If yes, which type of device I need to buy ? Like locked/unlocked and where can I buy them ? Are there any tutorial or links which can help me get started with this ?
I have some experience with Display code development on other platforms but, not on Android. 
Any tips and tricks will be highly appreciated. 
Thanks in Advance.

Please let me know if any part of the question is vague and needs elaboration.